# How to obtain only part of a word document?

Tags: extract, docx, doc

I'm in a scenario where I may have a very large word document (maybe 100GB), this is extremely large and doing any processing on this file will be costly. However, I only need the first few pages of the file, is there a way I can extract only the first few pages or first 10MB of the word doc and generate another word doc with the extracted data?

I've tried extracting only the first chunk of bytes with a filestream, but when exported to a doc file, the file is corrupt. I'm not surprised by this outcome, due to the bytes being cut at a random part.

Comment: What are the file type and extension?

Comment: @omegastripes .doc, .docx, maybe .xls

Comment: I would suggest to start with any structured storage viewer utility for .xls and .doc (MS Ofiice 2003 formats)  and 7z or other unzip utility for .xlsx and .docx (2007 +), try to find the utility able for fetching the data by chunks.

Comment: You'll have an easier time if its a docx rather than a .doc.  When you say large and 100GB, how much of that weight is text vs images?